# is this way of applying data augmentation correct

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow, image-processing, data-preprocessing, data-augmentation

I'm training a CNN and want to apply some data augmentation to my input images. I combined some code from tensorflow tutorials and have the following workflow:
I have a dataset containing all filenames. Then I map a function to that dataset that loads the labels and images and applies some data augmentation:

```py
def decode_image(img):
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(img)
  ...
```

```py
def process_path(file_path):
  label = label_from_file_path(file_path)
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_image(img)
  return img, label
```

After that I repeat, batch and prefetch the dataset containing images and labels. 
My question now is: is this the correct way to do data augmentation? I don't create new artificial data as I only apply this once to each image, right? It should still increase the robustness of the network, but do I give up some potential here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you are attempting to conduct the data augmentation manually - i.e. make changes to each image and then work from there.

Without seeing results, I cannot say whether your method of doing so will yield high accuracy on your test set.

However, from my own experience - a good way of conducting data augmentation is by using the `ImageDataGenerator` to create modified images and thus increase the size of the training set.

François Chollet, the creator of Keras, explains how this can be implemented in the **Deep Learning with Python** text - I would recommend this as a source in understanding data augmentation further.

If it helps, here is an example of how an [image classifier](https://www.michael-grogan.com/image-recognition-with-keras-convolutional-neural-networks/) was built with Keras to distinguish between images of cars and planes.

Essentially, the analysis used 100 images for each class as training and validation (with 15 images across both classes used as the test set).

Data augmentation is used for the purposes of increasing the sample size for the two classes, which subsequently resulted in strong predictive performance across the test set.

You could check whether implementing data augmentation in this manner vs. your method ultimately yields better results.

Comment: I'm using tf.data for the augmentation as this is more efficient than Keras, but it should do the same. The dataset is technically infinite because of the `repeat()`. I'm just wandering if it always applies the same random change to each image, or a different one every epoch. The first option would be preferred of cause, because it increases the variety of the dataset even more.

Comment: Well, it depends on the changes you are making. e.g. flip_up_down is being used to flip the image horizontally. If the same procedures are being applied to all images, then I would have thought it might decrease dataset variability. That said, I would only know for sure from looking at the data itself.